# AMELIA bounds R

Tags: r, missing-data

I can't have positive inputs even applying bounds in AMELIA, I have some negative numbers in my results and a warning :

Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

My code is:

```
library(Amelia)

data <- read.table(file='Test.csv', sep=',', header=T, row.names=1)

x <- 30106
y <- 1

bds <- matrix(c(3, y, x), nrow = 1, ncol = 3)

a.out.bsd <- amelia(data, bound = bds, max.resample = 10, ords=c("distance_to_center", "stars", "city_id"))

out <- range(a.out.bsd$imputations$imp1[is.na(data[, 3]), 3])

write.amelia(obj=a.out.bsd, file.stem="Trivago", format="csv")
```

---

**CSV**

> hotel_id,city_id,clicks,stars,distance_to_center
>   155796153,738,256,4,554
>   155827306,738,NA,4,624
>   155858459,738,349,4,434
>   155889612,738,NA,4,5391
>   155920765,772,3,3,3922
>   155951918,772,10,4,750
>   155983071,772,1,3,3133
>   156014224,772,0,3,5411
>   156045377,772,0,4,4757
>   156076530,772,NA,4,5087
>   156107683,772,2,0,3187
>   156138836,772,0,2,5974
>   156169989,772,NA,3,5256

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, this happens when you don't put any index number column, it seems Amelia needs this to apply boundaries.

```
hotel_id    city_id clicks  stars   distance_to_center
```

1   155796153   738 256 4   554

2   155827306   738 NA  4   624

3   155858459   738 349 4   434

4   155889612   738 NA  4   5391

5   155920765   772 3   3   3922

6   155951918   772 10  4   750

7   155983071   772 1   3   3133

8   156014224   772 0   3   5411

9   156045377   772 0   4   4757